# convert object (numeric value) to datetime using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have the data with time column as shown below, how to convert this as date and time using pandas

[image: datetime]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `df`:

```
In [208]: df
Out[208]: 
         Time
0  2384798300
1  1500353475
2  7006557825
3  1239779541
4  1237529231
```

Use [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [200]: from datetime import datetime

In [209]: df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x))

In [210]: df
Out[210]: 
                   Time
0   2045-07-28 01:28:20
1   2017-07-18 10:21:15
2   2192-01-11 15:33:45
3   2009-04-15 12:42:21
4   2009-03-20 11:37:11
```

Comment: actually I need it in a format of %d%m%Y %H:%M:%S... can you help me? I tried the code you provided with the required format, but it gives an error

Comment: @Beginner Please check my updated answer.

Comment: your answer may be right, but my data has 13 digits which leads to an error OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long, I tried converting to int, but does not work.... df1['Time'] = df1['properties.time'].astype(int).apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x))